# how to validate incoming edge towards source from target in mxgraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph

Hi i'm facing a problem with respect to edge validation

**Note:** any approach is most welcomed but should solve the problem

below is my requirement

1. source can have any following Action_* like this

> Source -> Action_1 -> Action_2

2. i want to avoid any Action_* coming against/towards source

> Source -> Action_1 <- Action_2

**Below Gif shows my requirement**

[image]

in above gif the text appears is **This one i want to avoid**

here is what i have tried

```
graph.multiplicities.push(new mxMultiplicity(
   true, 'Source', null, null, 1, 1, ['Action_1','Action_2'],
   'Source can have 1 Action and from there it can be multiple',
   null));

graph.multiplicities.push(new mxMultiplicity(
    false, 'Source', null, null, 0, 0, null,
   'Source Must Have No Incoming Edge',
   null)); // Type does not matter
```

here is demo what i have referred https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/validation.html  and here is its code  https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/validation.html

Here is the `Multiplicity` params

```
mxMultiplicity(source,type,attr,value,min,max,validNeighbors,countError,typeError,validNeighborsAllowed)
```

Here is its documentation : https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxMultiplicity-js.html

Here is what I have tried

```html
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2006-2013, JGraph Ltd
  
  Validation example for mxGraph. This example demonstrates using
  multiplicities for automatically validating a graph.
-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Validation example for mxGraph</title>

    <!-- Sets the basepath for the library if not in same directory -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
            mxBasePath = 'https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src';
        </script>
        <script src="https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>

    <!-- Example code -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Program starts here. Creates a sample graph in the
        // DOM node with the specified ID. This function is invoked
        // from the onLoad event handler of the document (see below).
         graph = {};
        function main(container)
        {
            // Checks if the browser is supported
            if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
            {
                // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
                mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
            }
            else
            {
                var xmlDocument = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
                var sourceNode = xmlDocument.createElement('Source');
                var action_1 = xmlDocument.createElement('Action_1');
                var action_2 = xmlDocument.createElement('Action_2');
                
                // Creates the graph inside the given container
                graph = new mxGraph(container);
                graph.setConnectable(true);
                graph.setTooltips(true);
                graph.setAllowDanglingEdges(false);
                graph.setMultigraph(false);


  /** mxMultiplicity accepts the following below params (source,type,attr,value,min,max,validNeighbors,countError,typeError,validNeighborsAllowed)
                
  */

    
                graph.multiplicities.push(new mxMultiplicity(
                   true, 'Source', null, null, 1, 1, ['Action_1','Action_2'],
                   'Source can have 1 Action and from there it can be multiple',
                   null));

                graph.multiplicities.push(new mxMultiplicity(
                   false, 'Source', null, null, 0, 0, null,
                   'Source Must Have No Incoming Edge',
                   null)); // Type does not matter

                
                // Enables rubberband selection
                new mxRubberband(graph);


                // Removes cells when [DELETE] is pressed
                var keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(graph);
                keyHandler.bindKey(46, function(evt)
                {
                    if (graph.isEnabled())
                    {
                        graph.removeCells();
                    }
                });

                // Installs automatic validation (use editor.validation = true
                // if you are using an mxEditor instance)
                var listener = function(sender, evt)
                {
                    graph.validateGraph();
                };
                
                graph.getModel().addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE,listener);
                
                // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
                // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
                var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
                                
                // Adds cells to the model in a single step
                graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
                try
                {
                    var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, sourceNode, 20, 20, 80, 30);
                    var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, action_1, 200, 20, 80, 30);
                    var v5 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, action_2, 200, 120, 80, 30);
    
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Updates the display
                    graph.getModel().endUpdate();
                }
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>

<!-- Page passes the container for the graph to the program -->
<body onload="main(document.getElementById('graphContainer'))">

    <!-- Creates a container for the graph with a grid wallpaper -->
    <div id="graphContainer"
        style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:321px;height:281px;background:url('editors/images/grid.gif');cursor:default;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any kind of solution(s) most welcomed, but it should solve the problem

Comment: Despite of more than 100 views I'm not getting answer. Please let me know if anyone don't understand the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood that problem is that you was facing, you want to validation the graph that:

- From source vertex (source node), you can make any edge to any another vertex (node)
- If any target vertex(Action 1) already connected to source vertex, If any other target vertex (Action 2 3 4 5) want connect to source vertex, it must be connected to those which already connect to source vertex instead.
- Any vertex connected to source could not be target

Unfortunately, your current way is using mxMultiplicity cannot solve the problem because several reason(s):

- It only support 1-depth level neighbor (which mean you can specific rules for it's neighbor, not neighbor of neighbor
- It only support built-in validation, no support custom validation

So the solution is:

- Try to validation graph model yourself using graph model at change listener instead using mxMultiplicity and update the array of mxMultiplicity every time you create a edge
- Using another library for graph visualize
- No create edge if any condition is not satisfied (my way) (actually, it doesn't pop up a warning message)

Here is my template for you. You can check this out about it documentation here ([connection handler](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/handler/mxConnectionHandler-js.html))

```js
mxConnectionHandlerInsertEdge = mxConnectionHandler.prototype.insertEdge;
mxConnectionHandler.prototype.insertEdge = function (parent, id, value, source, target, style) {
var check
//    check if you are allow to insert edge

if (check) {
    return mxConnectionHandlerInsertEdge.apply(this, arguments);
}
return null

};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Validation example for mxGraph</title>

<!-- Sets the basepath for the library if not in same directory -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    mxBasePath = 'https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src';
</script>
<script src="https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>

<!-- Example code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Program starts here. Creates a sample graph in the
    // DOM node with the specified ID. This function is invoked
    // from the onLoad event handler of the document (see below).
    graph = {};
    function main(container) {
        // Checks if the browser is supported
        if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
            // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
            mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
        }
        else {
            var xmlDocument = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
            var sourceNode = xmlDocument.createElement('Source');
            var action_1 = xmlDocument.createElement('Action_1');
            var action_2 = xmlDocument.createElement('Action_2');
            var action_3 = xmlDocument.createElement('Action_3');
            var action_4 = xmlDocument.createElement('Action_4');

            // Creates the graph inside the given container
            graph = new mxGraph(container);
            graph.setConnectable(true);
            graph.setTooltips(true);
            graph.setAllowDanglingEdges(false);
            graph.setMultigraph(false);


            /** mxMultiplicity accepts the following below params (source,type,attr,value,min,max,validNeighbors,countError,typeError,validNeighborsAllowed)
                          
            */


            graph.multiplicities.push(new mxMultiplicity(
                true, 'Source', null, null, 1, 1, ['Action_1', 'Action_2'],
                'Source can have 1 Action and from there it can be multiple',
                null));

            graph.multiplicities.push(new mxMultiplicity(
                false, 'Source', null, null, 0, 0, null,
                'Source Must Have No Incoming Edge',
                null)); // Type does not matter


            // Enables rubberband selection
            new mxRubberband(graph);


            // Removes cells when [DELETE] is pressed
            var keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(graph);
            keyHandler.bindKey(46, function (evt) {
                if (graph.isEnabled()) {
                    graph.removeCells();
                }
            });

            // Installs automatic validation (use editor.validation = true
            // if you are using an mxEditor instance)
            var listener = function (sender, evt) {
                graph.validateGraph();
                // sender is the graph model

            };
            // complete the validation function here
            mxConnectionHandlerInsertEdge = mxConnectionHandler.prototype.insertEdge;
            mxConnectionHandler.prototype.insertEdge = function (parent, id, value, source, target, style) {
                var check
                //    check if you are allow to insert edge

                if (check) {
                    return mxConnectionHandlerInsertEdge.apply(this, arguments);
                }
                return null

            };


            graph.getModel().addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, listener);

            // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
            // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
            var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

            // Adds cells to the model in a single step
            graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
            try {
                var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, sourceNode, 20, 20, 80, 30);
                var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, action_1, 200, 20, 80, 30);
                var v5 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, action_2, 200, 120, 80, 30);
                var v6 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, action_3, 400, 120, 80, 30);
                var v7 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, action_4, 600, 120, 80, 30);
            }
            finally {
                // Updates the display
                graph.getModel().endUpdate();
            }
        }
    };
</script>
</head>

<!-- Page passes the container for the graph to the program -->

<body onload="main(document.getElementById('graphContainer'))">

<!-- Creates a container for the graph with a grid wallpaper -->
<div id="graphContainer"
    style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:1000px;height:1000px;background:url('editors/images/grid.gif');cursor:default;">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that's great you understood my problem, i'm not able to write the working code through your reference. can you please produce a snippet here (can be done by clicking <> icon)

Comment: still i have bounty grace period of 20hrs i will definitely  award bounty

Comment: I updated the snippet. Recently, I am interest in graph theory but I am busy :D

Comment: Great !!! but not able to connect any of them expected is from `source` to any `actions` .

Comment: You should spend time for better validation function. It just a template for me

Comment: After spending time I found solution with your template, thanks alot !!

Comment: I am happy that you figured out the solution. You're welcome.